# Why is an std::list allocator parameterised by the value_type as a default?

Tags: c++, memory-management, std

```
template <
  class T,
  class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
>
class list;
```

By declaring an `std::list<int>` variable, as shown below, I would ensure the type of `std::list<int>::allocator_type` is `std::allocator<int>`. Assuming a doubly linked list implementation, each internal node would be larger than the size of the `value_type`. Does that mean that an implementation would allocate memory twice upon each element insertion? Once for the element, and once for the node? The forward declaration of `std::list` is shown above for reference.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::list<int> mylist;
  mylist.push_front(9);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can look at the contents of the `<list>` header to see exactly how `std::list` uses the allocator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator#Notes), `std::list<T>` allocates its internal nodes (say class `Node<T>`) using `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::rebind_alloc<Node<T>>`, which is, by default, `Alloc<Node<T>, Args>` if `Allocator` is `Alloc<T, Args>`. So, when `std::allocator` is used, `std::list<T>` will use `std::allocator<Node<T>>` to allocate its internal nodes.

If you want to provide a custom allocator template `Alloc` and don't want `std::list<T>` to use `Alloc<Node<T>>`, you can provide a member template `rebind` for `Alloc`, then [the allocator `Alloc::rebind<Node<T>>::other` will be used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits#Member_alias_templates).